# How do I filter data to startswith instead of contains

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a UITableView that has a Search Controller for filtering the data using the code below

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
     let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text
     filteredArray = data.filter({ (country) -> Bool in let countryText: NSString = country as NSString         
     return (countryText.range(of: searchString!, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive).location) != NSNotFound })
     suggestionview.reloadData()
}
```

How do I make it so that the search filters the table by looking at the start of the string instead of matching anywhere.

For example currently if I type Lon into the search input I get a list of anything that contains Lon (still a huge list before getting to London).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `NSString`? Prefer `String` in Swift 3+:

```
filteredArray = data.filter({ (country) -> Bool in 
    let countryText: NSString = country as NSString         
    return (countryText.range(of: searchString!, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive).location) != NSNotFound })
```

=>

```
filteredArray = data.filter({ country -> Bool in 
    return country.range(of: searchString!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil })
```

You used the `.caseInsenstive` option, but there is also the [`.anchored`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1410321-anchored) one that migh interest you:

> Search is limited to start (or end, if `NSBackwardsSearch`) of source string.

```
filteredArray = data.filter({ country -> Bool in 
    return country.range(of: searchString!, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil })
```

Comment: This was way easier, I like both answers but this one just seems simpler. But what is the .anchored option it doesn't seem to be valid

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at **[hasPrefix(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1540100-hasprefix)**

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the string begins with the specified prefix.

For example:

```
let items = [
    "London",
    "Londis",
    "Somelond",
    "Freelond"
]

let searchTerm = "Lon"

for item in items.filter({ itm -> Bool in
    itm.lowercased().hasPrefix(
        searchTerm.lowercased()
    )
}) {
    print(item)
}

// Output
London
Londis
```

---

Or for your specific case:

```
filteredArray = data.filter({ country -> Bool in        
    country.lowercased().hasPrefix(
        searchString!.lowercased()
    )
)
```

Comment: "For example currently if I type Lon into the search input I get a list of anything that contains Lon (still a huge list before getting to London)."

Comment: @ElTomato thats right, `hasPrefix` is different to a `contains`

Comment: That's not what he or she wants.  He or she wants to return an exact match or matches, according to the quoted comment.

Comment: @ElTomato I think "how do I make it so that the search uses a starts with instead of match anywhere."

Comment: So OP wants prefix not contains

Comment: OMG! Thank you. I had a go with hasPrefix in the wee small hours with no luck but turns out I was doing it on the wrong variable.

Comment: Side note: letters like the `ß`  ("german double s" won't) pass the test wih lowercasing, while `.caseInsenstive` yes. There might be other cases in other languages. It depends if you want that use case or not.

Comment: Sample to illustrate and FYI (in case someday you confronts that issue): `let strings2 = ["SS", "ß", "ss"]; strings2.forEach { print("Testing: \($0)"); print("Prefix Lowercase: \($0.lowercased().hasPrefix("ß".lowercased()))"); print("Prefix Uppercase: \($0.lowercased().hasPrefix("ß".lowercased()))"); print("CaseInsensitive: \($0.range(of: "ß", options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil)") }`